# Do all browsers have local storage?

Tags: html, local-storage

I wanted to know if it's necessary to do a check if local storage is present or not when I try to use it.

Ie, I have this as a check:

```
  if (global.localStorage) {
    global.localStorage.setItem('layout', JSON.stringify({
      [key]: value
    }));
  }
```

Or can I use localStorage without this check?

Comment: Keep the check. Incognito mode usually doesnt let you use it. For more info: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage

Comment: Despite good browser compatibility, the check can act as a conditional for non-compatible Storage API browsers.

Comment: @castis Point of order and FYI, just tested using Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) of Chrome and I found that Incognito mode uses local storage in the same away as normal browsing. This comment is made 3 years after your original comment so perhaps the situation has subsequently changed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mozilla maintain a table of desktop and mobile browser support here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

[image]

Comment: It's a little more complicated than this because a lot of browsers heavily restrict localStorage in private browsing mode. So just because a browser allows localStorage does not mean that it's usable.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the full list of supported browsers [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=webstorage)

Comment: caniuse.com is always a great resource!